# Can Prehensile Hair perform combat maneuvers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

A witch's [prehensile hair](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/common-hexes/hex-prehensile-hair-su) is described as having a strength score and being able to manipulate objects as dexterously as a human hand (with the exception of weapons, probably for balance purposes).

Can a witch use this hair to perform combat maneuvers, say a grapple or trip substituting the witch's strength for the hair's?

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25717/what-attack-rolls-does-a-twf-3-rogue-1-white-haired-witch-get

Comment: I'm talking about the witch hex Prehensile Hair, not the white haired witch's ability White Hair.

Comment: I said it's related, I didn't say it's an answer. Adding "related" questions is mostly of benefit to others who arrive here from searches but find it's not exactly what they're looking for.

Comment: I believe this is a no, only because the prehensile hair counts as a secondary natural attack (like a wing) but I will double check that for you in a second.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes you may make combat maneuvers with prehensile hair**

Page 199 Core Rulebook: When you attempt to perform a combat maneuver, make an attack roll and add your CMB in place of your normal attack bonus. Add any bonuses you currently have on attack rolls due to spells, feats, and other effects. These bonuses must be applicable to the weapon or attack used to perform the maneuver.

Combat section: Attacks with secondary natural attacks are made using your base attack bonus minus 5.

So the combat maneuver check, which is an attack roll, specifically says incurs the penalties made on attack rolls. Thus you would make the attack roll with your CMB but incur the -5 penalty.

The witch can manipulate her hair as if it were a limb with a Strength score equal to her Intelligence score, thus you would use your intelligence in place of your strength in the CMB.

Comment: Isn't the -5 penalty for secondary natural attacks only when performing a full attack? If I only use the hair don't I get Full BAB?

Comment: DanceSC - didn't you mean *combat maneuvers* and not *attacks of opportunity* in the title? (didn't want to edit as I'm not sure) - you don't really mention AoO anywhere later...

Comment: @MrTumnus, "primery" or "secondary" are inherent types of [natural attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks) - for example, a tail slap (normally a secondary attack) always takes -5 penalty to attacks. It doesn't matter if it's a single attack or part of a full action multiple attacks. Note that in some cases creatures treat their secondary attacks as primary - but none of these cases apply to a humanoid witch with prehensile hair as far as I can tell.

Comment: Also, Note that having a natural attack generally allows you access to the [multiattack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/multiattack-combat) feat (although, since this attack is available for a limited time, DM's approval will be required) - at any rate, this feat reduces the penalty from -5 to -2.

Comment: @MrTumnus In *Pathfinder*--unlike *D&D 3.5*--secondary attacks are *always* secondary and take appropriate penalties, even when taking a standard attack to use just that attack, an attempt I think to make those rules more manageable.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Not quite. Pathfinder did narrow the qualifications down substantially on using secondary attacks as primary ones, but it can still be done if the creature's single secondary attack is the only attack they have (not good enough to be the only one they're using *at the moment*, they have to actually not have any others at all).

Comment: @MatthewNajmon Got it. If *all* the creature *has* is secondary attacks, one is primary. Sure.

Comment: @HeyICanChan No, even more restrictive than that. If they have 2 or more secondary attacks they stay all secondary. It's only if they have *exactly* one attack *and* that attack is of a secondary type, then it becomes primary.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon Wow. I hadn't realized. I'm used to *Pathfinder* as a player and hadn't bothered with the monster part much. It takes a long time for [light horses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/horse) to fight duels over leadership. Thanks, *Pathfinder*, for making that clearer than *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*!

Comment: @GoBLin Thanks! I can't believe I typed that x.x